# Using an objects list for each object java

Tags: java

my question is:
How would I as an admin (already have admin menu and everything setup) add hours played by a character (everytime they play a game, a new int is added to the list of how many hours played via code I've already made) on their own hoursPlayed list? These are two different classes and the main is in Game.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public Class Game{

private List<Player> players;

    public Game(){
    players = new ArrayList<>();

    players.add(new Player("Random Name", 20));
    players.add(new Player("Random NameTwo", 200));

    }

}


public Class Player{
    private List<> hoursPlayed = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;
    private int playerNumber; 

    public Player(String name, int playerNumber){
    this.name = name;
    this.playerNumber = number;

   }
}
```

If you have any questions let me know :)

Comment: How players are playing the game these are just two objects? Which code initialises the game and derive further?

Comment: I’ve only attached relevant code; I just want to know how to add code each players List(hoursPlayed)

Comment: Is there another way I can answer your question without posting all of my code? @code_mechanic

Comment: Its difficult to suggest anything with just 2 objects, without additional info this question have many answers

Comment: In the best way I can explain my own question: each “player” object [random Name and Random Name 2] have their own List of type hoursPlayed which simply takes an int value. I would like to be able to add seperate entries of hoursPlayed to the player List<hoursPlayed> but attach them to a specific player object

Comment: You can add a function in your Player class which will add the new hours to the list and call that function from your game logic.

Comment: What would the function look like? I’m not directly understanding how to add code to an object’s list

Comment: It would help to answer your question if you could add rough code around your whole use case, you don't have to put all the code, just add rough possible code that would use above two classes, then someone will answer this question, otherwise, with any answer you would have lot more questions.